# concatenate text files and import them into a SQLite DB

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, sqldf

Let us say I have thousands of comma separated text files with 1050 columns each (no header). Is there a way to concatenate and import all the text files into one table, one database in SQLite (Ideally I'd use R and sqldf to communicate with SQlite).

I.e.,

Each file is called, table1.txt, table2.txt, table3.txt; all of different number of rows, but same column types, and different unique IDs in the IDs column (first column of each file).

```
table1.txt
id1,20.3,1.2,3.4
id10,2.1,5.2,9.3
id21,20.5,1.2,8.4
table2.txt
id2,20.3,1.2,3.4
id92,2.1,5.2,9.3
table3.txt
id3,1.3,2.2,5.4
id30,9.1,4.4,9.3
```

The real example is pretty much the same but with more columns and more rows.  AS you can note the first column in each file corresponds to a unique ID.

Now I'd like my new table in supertable, in the DB, super.db to be (also uniquely indexed):

```
super.db - name of the DB
mysupertable - name of the table in the DB
myids,v1,v2,v3
id1,20.3,1.2,3.4
id10,2.1,5.2,9.3
id21,20.5,1.2,8.4
id2,20.3,1.2,3.4
id92,2.1,5.2,9.3
id3,1.3,2.2,5.4
id30,9.1,4.4,9.3
```

For reference, I am using SQLite3; and I am looking for a SQL command that I can run on the background without logging interactively into the sqlite3 interpreter, i.e., IMPORT bla INTO,...

I could try in unix:

```
cat *.txt > allmyfiles.txt
```

and then a .sql file,

```
CREATE TABLE test (myids varchar(255), v1 float, v2 float, v3 float);
.separator ,
.import output.csv test
```

But this command does not work since I am using R `sqldf library`, and `dbGetQuery(db, sql)` and I have no idea how to create such string in R without getting an error.

p.s. I asked a similar Q for appending tables from a DB but this time I need to append/import text files not tables from a DB.

Comment: You should take a look at RSQLite package for creating tables from R into a SQLite DB. The ```sqldf``` package is for using SQL inside R. Take a look at page 12 of the [RSQLite manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/RSQLite.pdf). ```dbWriteTable()``` is probably what you need. Try to create one table, and then try to loop for the rest.

Comment: You can use the `sqlite3` program that comes with SQLite to create the database in the way you show and then use sqldf, or more likely RSQLite directly, from R on the database so created.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sqlite database files anyway, you might want to consider working with RSQLite.

```
install.packages( "RSQLite" )        # will install package "DBI"
library( RSQLite )
db <- dbConnect( dbDriver("SQLite"), dbname = "super.db" )
```

You still can use the unix command within R which should be faster than any loop in R, using the `system()` command:

```
system( "cat *.txt > allmyfiles.txt" )
```

Provided that your `allmyfiles.txt` has a consistent format, you can import it as a data.frame into R

```
allMyFiles <- read.table( "allmyfiles.txt", header = FALSE, sep = "," )
```

and write it to your database, following @Martín Bel's advice, with something like

```
dbWriteTable( db, "mysupertable", allMyFiles, overwrite = TRUE, append = FALSE )
```

*EDIT:*

Or, if you don't want to route your data through R,you can again resort to using the `system()` command. This may get you started:

You have a file with the data you want to get into SQLite called `allmyfiles.txt`. Create a file called `table.sql` with this content (obviously the structure must match):

```
CREATE TABLE mysupertable (myids varchar(255), v1 float, v2 float, v3 float);
.separator ,
.import allmyfiles.txt mysupertable
```

and call it from R with

```
system( "sqlite3 super.db < table.sql" )
```

That should avoid routing the data through R but still do all the work from within R.

Comment: thanks.  That makes sense.  I'd say it is quite inefficient though since allmyfiles.txt is a large file so reading in R and writing to the DB is redundant.  The nicest would be to have one command that talks to the DB and imports all the files, but no idea if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at termsql:

https://gitorious.org/termsql/pages/Home

cat *.txt | termsql -d ',' -t mysupertable -c 'myids,v1,v2,v3' -o mynew.db

This should do the job.